# Splitting output to two terminals

Tags: linux, terminal, redirection

How can I split an output of a command to two terminals? one will get stdout and the other will get stderr. The best I could do is:
On first terminal:

```
bash
command args 2> errors
```

and on second terminal

```
tcsh
while 1
    cat errors
    sleep 1
end
```

This works ok but it prints the errors over and over again every time, is there any better way to redirect the errors to another terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is 100 % correct.

Do the same thing on the first terminal, and on the second terminal don't use a "while" at all. Use `tail -f errors` to tail the errors file.